# Python tkinter says button not defined.Im a newby so help out.i have imported tkinter and button class too.It appears but when clicked shows error

Tags: python, button, tkinter

This is my code for a simple tictac game and button when clicked shows error

[image]

Comment: Post your code @veny O

Comment: I think you refer to `button1` in the `command` option.  Set `command` option in separate statement: `button1.config(command=...)` instead of in `Button(...)`.

Comment: It clearly shows you are referring `button1` as `botton1` that's why you get a `NameError`. Also you have imported `tkinter` and accessing `Tkinter` with capital T. **Python is Case Senstive**

Comment: please don't post pictures of code and stack traces. Pictures aren't searchable or copyable, and the visually impaired can't read them at all.

Answer (score -1):

there can be a problem in submit command.

button_7 = Button(win, text='7', padx=20, pady=10, bg='#cad45d', command=lambda : on_click(7))
try this